# Managing password change in my application

Tags: android, change-password

I am creating android application which has login and change password functionality.
But When user changes password from website then how would I know in Application that password has been changed?

Comment: Trigger a notification to app and show alter to user that password has been change or something like that.

Comment: If you are using an authentication token, you can revoke the token when a password is changed so the user will be logged out of mobile app too.

Comment: Give him a notification.

Comment: Use a trigger on the database table which writes a log in another table. Then check that table periodically. You might then be able to query something like "Who changed their passwords in the last 8 hours?".

Comment: notifications are temporary, you can send email to user's registered email id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send a reporting email is the way to go, you can start a lockdown of the account if the user doesn't recognize the activity.

All major websites do this (Google, Outlook, Facebook, etc) and they provide controls to recover your account if the password update was not triggered by the user.

As mentioned in comments you should revoke the login tokens that are enabled for that account, that should force a re-login action on every device the account has tokens, including the android app. Sending a notification seems too much but you can do it if you like.

If you are not using tokens is going to be a little more difficult and only you can find the right solution for your setup. I strongly suggest to transition to this paradigm.

Comment: Token solution is best for my application. Thank you.